# Are there any jQuery plugins to implement wordpress like simplereach slider

Tags: jquery

Are there any jQuery plugins to implement wordpress like simplereach content slider using jQuery.  Here I am giving the Image of the effect

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SimpleReach Slide is a Javascript only plugin.  Even with the CMS integrations (like Wordpress), it is still only Javascript that is rendered on the page.  It works in such a way that when our servers see your page for the first time, we index it and create a pool of 'recommendable articles.'  That pool allows us to do things like categorizing recommendations and slicing them up based on many factors (like user behavior, social, categories, etc). We only store enough information in order to make an intelligent recommendation.  Then when the user hits the page, the available information is used to make the most accurate recommendation possible for that user.

Something on the level of jQuery would likely be page level (or with some fancy trickery sitting in one of the browsers databases in HTML5).  Another jQuery like possibility would be to create a sliding widget and you pass the data to it from your own servers (effectively re-inventing the wheel with regards to the service that SimpleReach provides).  SimpleReach also provides additional items like analytics for The Slide and social buttons to increase sharing and engagement.  To mimic this with a jQuery plugin, one would have to use Google Analytics and create events for tracking slide interaction.

If you interested in something a little simpler with no analytics that works with Wordpress, you may want to check out the [Upprev](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/upprev/) plugin. It doesn't make recommendations like SimpleReach, it just shows the next article that is available for reading.

Disclaimer: I work for [SimpleReach](http://www.simplereach.com/).

Answer (score 0):

[Simplereach](http://simplereach.com/) themselves have a pure, non-jQuery plugin.

- http://simplereach.com/docs/publisher/website

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that they removed it, i got a 404.